# Bootstrap column does not go to the next line on small screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a form field with 4 buttons in the same row. I'm using Bootstrap and since I wanted the field and buttons to be vertically aligned, so I made a css class `vcenter` for it.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v9ec3/856/) with the code

**HTML**

```
<form>
                <div class="row stopWrap">
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 vcenter">
                        <label for="inputFirstName">First Name</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" placeholder="First Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-center vcenter">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" aria-label="Left Align">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </button>

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" aria-label="Left Align">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </button>

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" aria-label="Left Align">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </button>

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" aria-label="Left Align">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
```

**CSS**

```
.stopWrap{
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.vcenter {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 float: none;
}
```

Comment: What is the desired behavior as screen size reduces? Do you want the `first name` field to get smaller and the buttons remain beside it, or do you want the buttons to jump down to the next line, or ?

Comment: @gibberish I want the buttons to jump down to the next line. I used `col-xs-12` but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: is this what you expected: http://jsfiddle.net/v9ec3/857/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/orkyc42p/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to `float:none` which overrides bootstrap `float:left`.
That's why it does not go to the next line.

In your case, you should not use your `vcenter`. Remove it and add something like this to vertically align your buttons:

```
<div>
   &nbsp;
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5sceeno8/

It looks like a hack, but it's not because you set your `<input type="email" />` width to 100%, you clearly want to display the label and your input on separate lines. Similar to this:

```
<div>
    <label for="inputFirstName">First Name</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" placeholder="First Name">
</div>
```

After using `&nbsp;`, our button block has a similar structure to the input:

```
<div>
   &nbsp; //this is the replacement for <label> above which has the same height.
</div>
<div>
   //our buttons here
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this and it works, but I'd like to know that how did adding `&nbsp` correct the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the buttons in a `.row-fluid`, and make each button a `.span3`?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a media query to adjust the float as bootstrap breaks at the `col-xs-12` breakpoint (768px):

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #mybutt{float:left !important;text-align:left;}
}
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v9ec3/859/)</kbd>

This allows you to keep your `.vcenter` class, if desired, and do other necessary things (such as `text-align:left`).